# local variable 'username' referenced before assignment django

Tags: python, django, session, django-views

I have created a function called a panel.
When i run the server it gives an error " UnboundLocalError at /service-panel/ local variable 'username' referenced before assignment" .
I don't know what is getting wrong.

**Here is views.py**

```
@login_required
def panel(request):
    if(request.session.has_key('username')):
        username = request.session['username']
        data = Enquiry.objects.filter(service=request.session['service'])

    return render(request, 'service-provider-panel/base.html', {'username':username, 'data':data})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a logical error:

```
@login_required
def panel(request):
    if(request.session.has_key('username')):
        username = request.session['username']
        data = Enquiry.objects.filter(service=request.session['service'])
    else:
        # else statement is needed because the variables username and data must be defined.
        username = None
        data = None

    return render(request, 'service-provider-panel/base.html', {'username':username, 'data':data})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the condition `request.session.has_key('username')` can be `False`. Then, the `username` variable will not be assigned. The same with `data` variable.

A solution could be:

```py
@login_required
def panel(request):
    username = None
    data = None
    if(request.session.has_key('username')):
        username = request.session['username']
        data = Enquiry.objects.filter(service=request.session['service'])

    return render(request, 'service-provider-panel/base.html', {'username':username, 'data':data})
```

You will need to control the logic in the template (`service-provider-panel/base.html`) when `data` or `username` is `None`.